Expo App not loading after successful build
I have an Expo all that is working perfectly in Expo Go. I am looking to test using development build. The build downloads to my phone but when I click on it, I see:
"No bundle URL present. Please make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle."

Even when I go to scan the QR code it presents when I run npx expo start , it says "No usable data found"

Anyone who has had experience with Expo, your help would be highly appreciated. Thank you
